# HTML code from text area rendered in DIV

Tags: jquery

I've searched high and low for a solution to my problem but unfortunately could not find anything of use, so I was wondering if you guys could help me.

I want the HTML code typed into a text area to be rendered in a DIV element on the same page, in real-time. At the moment, I have:

```
$('#codeBox').keyup(function() {
    var keyed = $('#codeBox').val();
    $("#preview").html(keyed);
});
```

I hope I formatted that correctly. This may well be (and normally is) a case of 'the answer was right in front of me all along', sorry if that's the case!

Is there a problem with my code? Could you guys suggest an alternative?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this inside document ready handler? Does the event gets triggered at all?

Comment: Your code looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fv6bk/

Comment: As your `id` is 'codeBox' I'm guessing your issue might have something to do with HTML encoding, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ2Bm/ (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery).

Comment: That's strange. I use the code 'as is' with a syntax-highlighting plugin, could be that.

Comment: If this a codemirror e.g. than u need to handle onchange-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618445/how-to-get-the-output-in-a-div-when-a-textarea-is-modified   OR    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893883/call-back-editable-iframes-changes-into-codemirror?noredirect=1#comment31363157_20893883

Comment: Thank you Neha! Problem solved. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put greater than and less than signs in an element's **innerHTML,** so you need to use **Entities** because of greater than and less than signs:

```
$('#codeBox').keyup(function() {
  var keyed = $('#codeBox').val();
    keyed = keyed.replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    keyed = keyed.replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
  $("#preview").html(keyed);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fv6bk/1/)**

Comment: @user2559745 I'm sorry to hear this, I'll look into it

Comment: @user2559745  Can you make a fiddle, please?

Comment: Man of Snow, bearing in mind I'm 15 (novice at this stuff), it's probable that I'm at fault. But otherwise, with a normal text area (no Codemirror JS) it works. And I don't think that would be possible as I would need the accompanying files for Codemirror.

Comment: @user2559745 And I'm 13 ;) so can you at least provide me the URL for codemirror's API?  If you don't, I can download it, but I'm currently working with JSFiddle

Comment: @user2559745 That's not what I meant, but I found it on gitHub and I'm currently trying to fix this issue

Comment: Man of Snow, problem solved above - thanks for all your help buddy! :)

Comment: @user2559745 How did you solve the problem, so I can add it to my answer to help other people?